# Reading from binary file in C

Tags: c

I have the following struct:

```
struct Records
{
    int Number;
    char Name[20];
    float Salary;
};
```

Writing two records using:

```
fwrite(&MyRecords.Number, sizeof(&MyRecords.Number), 1, binaryfile);
fwrite(&MyRecords.Name, sizeof(&MyRecords.Name), 1, binaryfile);
fwrite(&MyRecords.Salary, sizeof(&MyRecords.Salary), 1, binaryfile);
```

After writing, Im having trouble reading from it.

```
FILE * read;
read = fopen("binaryfile.dat","rb");

for(int x =0;x<2;x++)
{
fread(&records.Number, sizeof(records.Number), 1, read);
fread(&records.Name, sizeof(records.Name), 1, read);
fread(&records.Salary, sizeof(records.Salary), 1, read);
printf("%d %s %f\n",records.Number,records.Name,records.Salary);
}
```

The first line gets printed twice, and the float comes out as some weird number. I've double and tripled checked for the past 2 hours yet I cant find out what im doing wrong :(

Comment: Can you show us how you open binaryfile and read files?

Comment: Edited my post to add it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the whole struct in one go instead, makes it easier to read:

```
fwrite(&MyRecords, sizeof(MyRecords), 1, binaryfile);
```

besides that you also have wrong `sizeof()` it shouldn't be `sizeof(&MyRec..)` it should be `sizeof(MyRec..)` without `&`.

Comment: Thanks, removing the & in the sizeof fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

```
sizeof(&foo)
```

Is not the same as:

```
sizeof(foo)
```

Comment: It can be a number of things. 1) You haven't opened the file in binary mode (make sure `"b"` is specified for `fopen`). 2) `Name` might not have been null-terminated to start with (hint: create a `print` routine that you can call before writing the data to a file and after reading it back in, that way you could tell of the data was OK to start with).